# Tipsy Plugin not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, tipsy

I've used [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) on my [webpage](http://designsblog.in/test/tipsyTest.html), it is working fine on all browsers except IE9 (well i do not check it on earlier IE versions).
The tooltips are displayed on hover without any effect. What I am doing wrong here?
or is it a bug instead? Any solutions? 
**Update**
Used it on the share buttons in sidebar and footer social contact icons.
**Update**
On the test page provided, tooltip is used on the give link.

Answer (score -1):

It's a problem with your css. Set your A tags to inline-block, don't float the images inside them and you will see a big change in footer. The images are floating outsilde of the A tags. Can see it easily when you inspect html in Firebug or IE console

Comment: Yeah its a problem in CSS and I am working on it, but `tipsy` did not depend at all on the page's CSS, it has its own css properties defined, and if the CSS will be the reason then other browsers should also respond to that, also, the `title` is readily displayed up in IE, if it has a CSS problem than title will get distorted somewhere on the page. . .

Comment: IE has hard time positioing A tags that aren't dimensioned or have solid css, tooltip needs that position to reference

Comment: Here is not the point of positioning of `a` tag, and if _positioning_ is a problem than what about the `side` column's _share buttons_?

Comment: same problem..try giving side A tags some dimensions will likely respond better

Comment: Look at this link now: http://designsblog.in/test/tipsyTest.html  ...Now what you say what's happenining here (with no external CSS used)??? Plugin on the link working well in all other browsers except IE9.